# Custom Gson deserialization for primitive arrays

Tags: java, gson, deserialization, primitive-types

Given the following Json snippet:

```
    String json = "{ \"test\" : [1, 2.5, 4, 5.66] }";
```

and the call to GSON:

```
    Map obj = gson.fromJson(array, Map.class);
```

I get a properly parsed Java object that is a LinkedHashMap containing an ArrayList of Doubles.  For the purposes of my program, I would like a result to contain primitive versions of arrays and numbers.  So preferably, I would get a Map containing a `double[]` rather than `ArrayList<Double>`.

I have looked into custom deserialization via the `JsonDeserializer<?>` interface but have not successfully implemented it such that `ArrayLists` become `[]`
's and `Doubles` becomes `doubles`.

What must I understand to be able to tell GSON to choose Array opposed to ArrayList and double opposed to Double when parsing arbitrary JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new TypeToken<LinkedHashMap <String, double[]>>(){}.getType()` instead of `Map.class`

Here is demo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    String array = "{ \"test\" : [1, 2.5, 4, 5.66] }";

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    LinkedHashMap <String, double[]> obj 
      = gson.fromJson(array, new TypeToken<LinkedHashMap<String, double[]>>(){}.getType());

    for (Map.Entry<String, double[]> entry : obj.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + 
                           ", Value = " + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()));
    }
}
```